# Grails 2.2.4 unit test exception | java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:

Tags: unit-testing, grails, mocking, grails-orm

I am getting an exception while unit testing this line

```
def user = User.findAll("from User u sort by u.date")
```

String-based queries like [findAll] are currently not supported in this implementation of GORM. Use criteria instead.

I mocked findAll like this

```
def mockUser= mockFor(User)
        mockUser.demand.static.findAll(1) { query ->
            return User.list()
        }
```

This used to work find in grails 1.3.7 but now I upgraded it to 2.2.4, it gave me above excpetion

Comment: Can you share the full test?

Comment: Hey..i don't really know what the issue was but I added parameter type and it got working (String query ->)

Comment: Ok, so post your new code as answer :-)